# What is the type of linked list where order doesn't matter

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists

I'm reading the [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000693) book on Data Structures and it says the following about linked listed implementation:

> Insertion into a singly-linked list is a nice exercise in pointer
>   manipulation, as shown below. **Since we have no need to maintain the
>   list in any particular order**, we might as well insert each new item in
>   the simplest place. Insertion at the beginning of the list avoids any
>   need to traverse the list, but does require us to update the pointer
>   (denoted l) to the head of the data structure.

I'm wondering what kind of list is that because I can't use it for index based access. All other basic implementations I've seen provide index based access.

When searching for an item, their implementation shows direct object comparison:

```
list *search_list(list *l, item_type x)
{
    if (l == NULL) return(NULL);
    if (l->item == x)
        return(l);
    else
        return( search_list(l->next, x) );
}
```

So I'm thinking maybe they didn't account for index based access.

This book also distinguishes `Container` and `Dictionary` categories of DS:

> We use the term container to denote a data structure that permits
>   storage and retrieval of data items independent of content. They are
>   distinguished by the particular retrieval order they support (LIFO,
>   FIFO). By contrast, dictionaries are abstract data types that retrieve
>   based on key values or content.

It seems that the linked listed implementation at hand falls into a container category with the object reference as the key, something alike a map DS.

Is this assumption valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the book you are referencing, and it does appear that Steven Skiena made an unordered Dictionary implemented as a linked list.  It's not a terribly efficient data structure, but he was only using it to illustrate basic linked list coding techniques, so I expect he just wanted to keep things as simple as possible.

For what it's worth, a stack is a container that only allows you to add to or access from the very top item, which isn't really *index based* in the way we'd usually use that term.  I mention this only to highlight that Containers do not need to have index-based retrieval.